# Selecting users from one table when not in the other

Tags: mysql, sql, anti-join

I have a query that selects a registration date of a user from one table.

```
SELECT DATE(registered)
FROM users
WHERE user_id= ".$currentUser."
ORDER BY registered ASC
LIMIT 1
```

I need to modify the original query by joining another table, to make sure that the user is not present in that second table ("access") where a member ID is below certain value and the ACCESS date is below certain date.

```
LEFT JOIN access ON (users.user_id = access.user_id)
WHERE access.user_id < 500
AND access.date ... after March 1, 2012
```

Not sure how to get those two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery, e.g.:

```
  SELECT DATE(u.registered)
    FROM users u
   WHERE u.user_id = ".$currentUser."

     AND NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT 1 
               FROM access a 
              WHERE u.user_id = a.user_id
                AND a.user_id < 500
                AND a.date > DATE '2012-03-01')

ORDER BY registered ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Some notes:
You still get a row back even if there is no matching row(s) in the `access` table.
You probably know this...`ASC` is the default sort order so you don't need to type it out.

Comment: Great! I just thought of something. I do need the date to be a.date > DATE '2012-03-01' but it can not be today's date either... Can I just add AND a.date != NOW() ?

Comment: Yeah, add one more line to the subquery:  `AND a.date <> CURDATE()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the entire condition in the join, otherwise you will effectively turn it into an inner join:

```
...
LEFT JOIN access ON (
  users.user_id = access.user_id
  AND access.user_id < 500
  AND access.date >= '20120301'
)
WHERE access.user_id is null
...
```

Comment: "from one table when not in the other" = anti-join.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Yes, that's what you do when you use a left join and check for null values.

Comment: @onedaywhen: If you are lucky the query planner will turn `not exists()` into a left join, because it's much more efficient.

Comment: "Yes, that's what you do when you use a left join and check for null values" -- I'd say it was the other way around: the concept is existential quantification, the relational operator is semi-difference (a.k.a. anti-join) and the implementation in SQL has, as is usual, about seven different ways. Personally, I avoid nulls like the plague and outer join is expressly designed to product nulls.

Comment: "If you are lucky the query planner will turn [your favoured choice of about seven candidate queries] into [the optimizer's favoured choice of about seven candidate queries]" -- I expect nothing less of a DBMS.

Comment: @onedaywhen: No, it's not the other way around, it's exactly like I said. You can use a left join to check for non-existing relations. It's as simple as that. Regarding your choise of solution, you are using an irrational reason to avoid a specific solution, but on the other hand you expect the database to convert your solution of choise to that specific solution that you try to avoid.

Comment: "You can use a left join to check for non-existing relations" -- did you mean 'tuples' rather than 'relations'? "an irrational reason" -- my reason for avoiding nulls is that they lead to mistakes (recall you made one yourself last week, for which I blame nulls and not you!) "you expect the database to" -- did you mean 'DBMS' rather than 'database'? "you expect the [DBMS] to convert your solution of choise to that specific solution that you try to avoid" -- no, I expect it to pick the best plan.

Comment: @onedaywhen: No, I didn't mean tuples, I meant relations. Perhaps you thought that I meant relation between tables, but I mean relations between records. A relation between tables can't be non-existing, it's always there even if there are not records that fulfill it. Using null doesn't in itself lead to mistakes, so your reason for avoid null is not rational. Perhaps I could use "DBMS" sometimes when I use "database", but I don't make that distinction unless nessecary, because it serves no purpose.