# Omitting one row from a table if it exists on a day and period in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that omits a row from another table if found on a certain day/time but it includes it if it does.

It currently omits the row but does not include it if not found on a certain day/time. How can I rectify this?

```
SELECT * FROM ts_room
WHERE
id <>
(SELECT status
FROM ts_request rq
LEFT JOIN ts_allocation a ON a.request_id = rq.id
WHERE 
day_id=1 AND period_id=2
OR a.status IS NOT NULL
AND a.status IN ('Pending','Declined','Failed'))
```

Here is my SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8da9/49

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting users from one table when not in the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552441/selecting-users-from-one-table-when-not-in-the-other)

Comment: I'm not following.  Should there be a negative in here?  `if found on a certain day/time but it includes it if it does`.